# How to insert the values from REST

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, webservices, rest

**VF Page Screenshot**

[image]

**This is my VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="cntrycontroller" >
<apex:form >
<apex:outputText >Enter a 2 digit country  :  </apex:outputText>
<p/>
<apex:inputtext value="{!input_country}" id="id_inptext"/>
<apex:commandButton id="btn" action="{!fetch_data}"  value="Get from Webservice"/>
<p/>
<apex:outputText >Status : {!response_status}</apex:outputText>
<p/>
<apex:outputtext >Status Code : {!response_status_code}</apex:outputtext>


</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller Code**

```
public with sharing class cntrycontroller {


public PageReference fetch_data() {

    HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
    String url = 'http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/'+input_country;
    req.setEndPoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');//DONT FORGET THIS GUY .HE IS IMPORTANT
    HTTP h = new HTTP();
    HTTPResponse resp = h.send(req);
    response_status = resp.getStatus();
    response_status_code = String.ValueOf(resp.getStatusCode());       

    return null;
}

public String input_country{get;set;}
public String response_status{get;set;}
public String response_status_code{get;set;}

 public cntrycontroller(){
  input_country = 'IN';
 }
}
```

**URL Response**
[image]

I am getting **"alpha3_code"** value when passing the input country. The aim is i have to insert this value  in CountryCode__c field of County__C object.

Please help me to solve this query.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You would need to retrieve, and parse the contents of the body returned in the response. Something like this:

```
HTTPResponse resp = h.send(req);
String json = resp.getBody();
Map<String,Object> responseMap = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(json);
Map<String,Object> restResponseMap = (Map<String,Object>)responseMap.get('RestResponse');
Map<String,Object> resultMap = (Map<String,Object>)restResponseMap.get('result');
String alpha3code = (String)resultMap.get('alpha3_code');

insert new Country__c(CountryCode__c = alpha3code);
```

NB. I have not tested this, there may be syntax errors but in essence this is what you'd need to do.